# Codename One ShareButton for videos and map points

Tags: codenameone

Usually it’s possible to share a video from an app to another. I suppose it’s possible also to share map points (latitude and longitude) between apps that can understand coordinates.

Why does Codename One ShareButton allow only to share text and images? Are there technical restrictions or is a RFE possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the API assumes it but it's possible to add a new API. One thing that is missing is sharing URI's which I assume is the way to share location coordinates as I haven't tried that before.